# Javascript, Jquery inside Rails Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

Can I use javascript inside rails helper ?

If yes then how?

I am trying with the javascript tag inside ***application_helper.rb***

```
javascript_tag "$('#all_records tr').slice(- (<%= no_of_rows_remove %>)).remove();"
```

but it doesn't working.

can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: what were you attempting to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 1):

Your helper function should be like:

```
def helper_function_name
  number_of_rows_to_remove = 10
  js = "$('#all_records tr').slice(#{number_of_rows_to_remove}).remove();"
  return js.html_safe
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= helper_function_name %>
```

Comment: Thanks @abhilash reddy , actually I am calling helper from js.erb file and the solution you have given to me is not working.

Comment: Please update your question with js.erb code, So that we can help you better.